# Search Text in PDFViewWPF

Tags: pdf, search, pdftron

I'm using PDFNet to display PDF-files in my WPF application.
I need to provide a search mode where one can enter a search term which will be searched in the whole PDF-file. I found [FindText](https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/docs/PDFNet/html/M_pdftron_PDF_PDFViewWPF_FindText.htm) in the documentation, but it doesn't seem to work properly. If I'm going to execute the method I can see a thread ending in my console output in Visual Studio - so it seems to run.
If I'm going to click the button multiple times the view will be scrolled to the corresponding find results but sometimes (or mainly) the text will not be selected.

The method which will be executed looks like the following:

```
private void Toolbar_DocumentSearch_Click(System.Object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) {
    if (this.TbSearchTerm.Text.Length > 0) {
        _pdfview.FindText(this.TbSearchTerm.Text, false, false, false, false);
    }
}
```

Any hint on what I'm doing wrong?

Additional information:
If I've searching through the whole document, it starts from the beginning. Then the first find result will be selected but none other until the next find result is on the next page.

Comment: "but sometimes (or mainly) the text will not be selected." Is this file specific, or occurs with every file?

Comment: It's not file specific, it occurs with each document I tested.

Comment: The issue with text not highlighting sounds like a bug. What version of PDFNet are you using? Are you able to reproduce using our PDFViewWPFTest sample project that comes with our SDK.

Comment: I'm using version 6.7.1, update from 6.3.2 which was used before. I'll try to reproduce the problem later this day.

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to reproduce the problem using the PDFViewWPFTest sample project and my PDF files.

Comment: It would appear then that some change/code in your project is triggering this. Are you able to provide a video of the issue? Or better yet are you able to send me a project that has the issue? If confidential you can send directly to PDFTron support.

Comment: I'm not allowed to send the whole project because it's property of the company I work at. I will do some further research to find the problem. If I'll not find the mistake I will contact you through the PDFTron support with a video of the issue. Thank you so far!

Answer (score 1):

The built it in text search in PDFViewWPF is the type of search you get when you typically select ctrl-f when viewing.

PDFViewWPF.FindText does search the entire document, but does not display all the results in a window or control

You can add your own full text search control using the TextSearch class.
https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/samplecode/TextSearchTest.cs.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Like in the typical ctrl-f text search, i expect the results to be highlighted, but this doesn't happen. The document will scrolled down to the next find result, but the highlighting doens't work. In an older application of ours it works. Maybe I should give the TextSearch class a try.